# Crash in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

Getting  error:

Unable to load class named 'MyClass' for entity 'Myentity'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

my code is:

```
import CoreData

class MyClass: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var descriptions: String
    @NSManaged var status: String
    @NSManaged var issuePagePath: String
}
```

Crash point:

```
  let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Myentity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! MyClass
```

Comment: where is `MyEntity` defined?

Comment: "Myentity " defined in my "core_data.xcdatamodeld" file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create an entity called "Myentity", but your actual entity is `MyClass`. Try creating an entity of `MyClass`.

```
let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyClass", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! MyClass
```

Comment: Sorry not working, MyClass is my custom class of NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
@objc(MyClass)
```

before:

```
class MyClass: NSManagedObject
```